# flutter: how to get the button widget in this flutter test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm working with `flutter test`. I want to test something after `tap a widget` but I don't know how to find the button. Because I custom it rather than use `Icon` or `iconButton`. Also, I can't find it according to its `text` because another widget has the same name. And also two `InkWell` widget as you can see. My basic test code is here.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';

import 'package:project/page/login.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('login page test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame
    await tester.pumpWidget(Login());

    expect(find.text('login'), findsNWidgets(2));
    expect(find.text('ID'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('password'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('end'), findsOneWidget);

    // how to find my custom button
    await tester.tap((find.byElementType(InkWell)));  <- my question here

    // test other things after tapping the button.
  });

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this you have to mention key (key: const Key("btnLogin"),)

```
ElevatedButton(
          key: const Key("btnLogin"),
          onPressed: () {
            _decrementCounter();
          },
          child: const Text(
            " Login ",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
```

in Widget test

```
await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('btnLogin')));
await tester.pump();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    InkWell(
          key: const Key("btnLogin"),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _decrementCounter();
            },
            child: const Text(
              " Login ",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Like this also we can do

```
await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('btnLogin')));
await tester.pump();
```

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation on what does your code do?

Answer (score 1):

give a key name to your inkwell button like this.

**- in your login screen.**

```
     InkWell(
      key: const Key("login"),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
        },
        child: const Text(
          " Login ",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    ),

 **- in your testing file**
    
   var loginButton = find.byKey(const Key('login'));
   await tester.tap(loginButton );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *find.byElementType()* use ***find.byType()***.

So your code will be like this:

> await tester.tap((find.byType(InkWell)));